# UIPageViewController PageCurl scroll one page at a time

Tags: cocoa-touch, scroll, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, page-curl

After user swipes to the page (PageCurl effect) I'd like to disable swipe to the next page until he does something on the current page. 
I have in the viewDidAppear method [self checkScrolling]; which actually works, but with a delay. If I swipe pages in normal pace, everything works (it gets called), but if I do several fast swipes in a row, pages are scrolled, but method is not called.

Any advice on the way to enable scrolling only one page until there is permission allow scrolling tot he next?

Janis

Comment: Have you tried calling your checkScrolling method in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear? I'd assume viewDidAppear only gets called after the curl animation has finished, but viewWillAppear should be called when the content controller is added to the UIPageViewController.

Comment: if it is called in viewWillAppear  the page stays half turned